# clang can't find STL but gcc can

Tags: xcode, development

I wrote a simple C++ program:

```
    #include <vector>
    
    int main(void) {
        return 0;
    }
```

When I try to compile with clang, I get this :

```
    $ clang truc.c        
    truc.c:1:10: fatal error: 'vector' file not found
    #include <vector>
             ^~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
```

When I try to compile with g++, I get this :

```
    $ g++ truc.c 
    clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
```

What can I do to make it so that clang works too? I have Xcode 11.2, CommandLineTools for 11.2, OSX 10.15.1.

I ran

```
xcode-select --install
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Alternatively, I could not use clang and use g++ instead. I have to use a specific repo for school and they use scons and I don't really how to deal with that.

Comment: `<vector>` is C++ not C.  See [why do i need to include <vector> to use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228474/why-do-i-need-to-include-vector-to-use-them).  If you want a simple C program try [this](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/print-sentence).  In any case, programming questions are better asked on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions).

Comment: updated my post. i believe this is a osx related issue.

Comment: As it is C++ then if you rename `truc.c` to `truc.C` (case matters), `truc.cpp`,`truc.cc` ([etc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546107/2953889)) clang will compile it fine.  g++ will compile it but give a warning (because you've told it it is C++ by using C++ compiler).  Clang direct will not compile it as you've used `.c` which is for C programs by default.  I don't really see this is a macOS issue.

Comment: Mh.. It did resolve the issue. My apologies, I really thought the file extension carried no information whatsoever. Thanks, I guess it's not my xcode setup that is broken.